# Passing id through an link href in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes

is it possible to pass id through an link href in Laravel and display that page like /projects/display/2.

I have this link:

```
<td><a href="{{ url('projects/display', $projects->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">View</a></td>
```

It displays the id when hovering over the link as /projects/display/2. But whenever i click on the link i get an error message of:

```
 Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

I have a view setup called projects/display, plus routes and controller.

routes:

```
<?php


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function (){

    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');

    Route::get('/login', 'PagesController@getLogin');

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::get('/projects/display', 'ProjectsController@getDisplay');

    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');


});
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\project;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {



    }


    public function create()
    {
        return view('projects.create');
    }



    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(

            'name' => 'required|max:200',
            'description' => 'required'
        ));

        $project = new project;

        $project->name = $request->name;
        $project->description = $request->description;

        $project->save();

         Session::flash('success', 'The project was successfully created!');

        return redirect()->route('projects.show', $project->id);


    }


    public function show()
    {
        $project = Project::all(); 

        return view('projects.show')->withProject($project);

    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function getDisplay($id){


        $project = Project::find($id);

        return view('projects/display')->withProject($project);

    }





}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to change your route to:

```
Route::get('/projects/display/{id}', 'ProjectsController@getDisplay');
```

And then generate URL with:

```
{{ url('projects/display/'.$projects->id) }}
```

Comment: @steven Be sure to mark this as accepted when you're able, just in case others might have the same question.

Answer (score 4):

If you write route like below,

```
Route::get('/projects/display/{projectId}', 'ProjectsController@getDisplay')->name('displayProject');
```

You can use the name 'displayProject' in the href and pass the id as Array :

```
<td><a href="{{ route('displayProject', ['projects' => $projects->id]) }}" class="btn btn-info">View</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a parameterized route. Read more about them here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#required-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution:
In your blade file do like this

```
<a href="{{route('displayProject',"$id")}}">
  View
</a>
```

with this route , in route file

```
Route::get('/projects/display/{id}', 'ProjectsController@getDisplay');
```

$id is sent form your controller with compact

```
return view('viewPage', compact('id'));
```