# How to customize show function

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a question about functions. Its a really basic stuff. But I stucked at this point.

My goal is click catalogname and show all rows with same catalogname.

I wrote this lines.

```
public function bringItOn(Request $request)
    {
        $ctlgshow = Productcatalog::where('catalogname_id' , '=', $request->catalogname_id);
        return view('productcatalogs.showcatalog', compact('ctlgshow'));
    }
```

I am calling this function in my index table. I have 4 column and one of them is catalogname_id. When I clicked this column variables I am trying to show all rows catalogname_id = clicked index.

This is my main table.

```
 @foreach($a as $b)
     <tr>
         <td>{{$b->id}}</td>
         <td><a href="{{route('bringItOn')}}">{{$b->catalogname_id}}</a></td>
         <td>{{$b->c}}</td>
         <td>{{$b->d}}</td>
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Also my routes are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `get()` method to execute the query:

```
Productcatalog::where('catalogname_id', $request->catalogname_id)->get();
```

Also, you need to use the `ctlgshow` variable in `foreach` instead of `$a`:

```
@foreach($ctlgshow as $b)
```

Comment: I tried sir. But its not working. However i found main problem. When i write dd($request) its return empty. My clicking index is still right up there. I have declared as my main table. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I tried with get()
But dd($request) return null. What can be wrong?

Comment: @AliÖzen `get()` is not related to `$request` in any way.

Comment: I did not full express myself actually. 
dd($ctlgshow) is also returning null. Everything return null right now.

Comment: @AliÖzen you can't get `null` for `dd($ctlgshow)` when you're using `get()`. It will be a collection in any case.

Comment: When i try 
Productcatalog::where('catalogname_id', '1')->get();

Its work. It pull all rows catalogname_id = 1
but request is empty. $request->catalogname_id cant work.

Comment: @AliÖzen please show the form you're using to pass `catalogname_id`

Comment: <td><a href="{{route('bringItOn')}}">{{$b->catalogname_id}}</a></td>

I declared in post. This line is calling functions.

Comment: Your post so helpful for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41619194/9156043

I made this way. However I am getting all rows. I need to use where command. But i cant figure out how can i use in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Controller Code:

```
public function bringItOn(Request $request)
{   
    if(isset($request)) {
        $ctlgshows = Productcatalog::where('catalogname_id', $request->catalogname_id)->get();
    } else {
        $ctlgshows ="";
    }
    return view('productcatalogs.showcatalog', compact('ctlgshows'));
}
```

Blade Code:

```
@if($ctlgshows)
@foreach($ctlgshows as $ctlgshow)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$ctlgshow->id}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{route('ctlgshowringItOn')}}">{{$ctlgshow->catalogname_id}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$ctlgshow->c}}</td>
        <td>{{$ctlgshow->d}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
@else
Empty
@endif
```